# PHP mailer to send mail with HTML contents

Tags: php, email, sendmail, mailer

I am using php mail method to send HTML mails to people from my domain. I am using the following code to send mail

```
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
    mail($id, $subject, $message,$headers);
```

However, the problem is that the code doesnt work when the size of message increases. It works fine for smaller messages.

Is there any way to overcome that ??

Comment: Define "the code doesn't work."  Is there an error?  Does the mail server receive the SMTP connection?  Does it receive the mail?  What does the mail server do with the mail (which is outside the context of this code/question)?

Comment: for small messages, message is sent.

Comment: for larger messages, nothing happens. I set the mail fn as a boolean like
value = mail(....), n even the value is true for larger messages, but no mail is sent

Comment: Define "message is sent."  Can you check the logs on the mail server?  It's _highly_ likely that the problem is happening on the mail server and not in the code.  At least determine if the SMTP connection is being received by the mail server.

Comment: Are you sure "no mail is sent"?  Or do you mean "no mail is received _after_ being processed by the mail server"?  It seems like there's a large black box of mail processing happening that you're not even checking.

Comment: sorry, but i dont know abt that black box. I just meant no mail is received. I also cant find anything in the error log of that folder

Comment: Based on the information presented, I find it most likely that the larger HTML messages are being filtered by the mail server as potential spam by some heuristic.  There's no reason to indicate that the messages aren't being sent to the server (unless your debugging demonstrates otherwise, such as an SMTP connection not being opened).

Comment: hey it was due to lack of br tags in the HTML code. Thanks for suggestions anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. It was due to less number of breaking tags br in the html code. I introduced some br tags here and there and it flew :)